# display growl when page is loaded primefaces jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, load, growl

I have this commandButton :

```
    <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer" action="#{reglementClientMB.ajouter}" 
            process="@this @form" update="@form" >
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{reglementClientMB.est_ajouter}" value="false" />
            </p:commandButton>
```

the action method return to another page , I want to display one `p:growl` when the next page is loaded

I tested to put that is the constructor of its managed bean but the growl is displayed below data in the page

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, ""
                                + "Confirmation", "Réglement crée avec sucée"));

                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("messages");
```

how can I achieve this

thank you in advance

Answer (score 10):

The bean's constructor may be too late for the job if the `<p:growl>` is rendered before the bean is been constructed for the first time. E.g.

```
<p:growl />
...
<h:outputText value="#{bean.something}" />
```

It would only work if the bean is constructed before the `<p:growl>` is rendered.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.something}" />
...
<p:growl />
```

In order to solve your concrete problem, you'd need to do the job in a pre render view listener instead.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

With:

```
public void init() {
    // Add the desired message here.
}
```

Comment: i solved the problem by placing the message/growl at the end of my template code.. is that a good/acceptable practice? or am i going to run into problems with that?

Comment: @Jenson: As answered, you need to make sure that the message is added before the target message component is rendered. Which way you choose is up to you.