# Primefaces validation before open page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have grid name `personalDetails` with user personal details where field NIP is required.

```
            <p:inputText id="nip"
                value="NIP"
                required="true"
                maxlength="20"
                requiredMessage="Nip is required"
                >
                <p:ajax update=":#{p:component('nip')}" />
                <f:validator validatorId="NipValidator" />                  
            </p:inputText>
```

I select user personal details for database where NIP can be null. My question is how show `requiredMessage` on open page with user which do not have NIP?

Comment: Does it work with plain jsf tags like `h:inputText`?

Comment: If you want to get user attention to this field only when empty you might want to try `styleClass="#{empty someBean.NIP ? 'ui-state-error' : ''}"`.  Otherwise, you should probably bind the `inputText` to the bean and use `preRenderView`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16555885/1980659.